# Changing navigation back button icon dynamically doesn't work

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-actionbar-compat, android-navigation

I need to set navigation back button dynamically
when I do this `
`viewBinding.toolbar.navigationIcon?.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(theme.primaryTextColor), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY)` 
 it doesn't effect changing color or if I do

`viewBinding.toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back)` in MainActivity
where ic_back is white back button it doesn't work  it shows back button 
or if I add this   `app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_back"` in xml it doesn't work 
but when I set `app:theme="@style/ToolbarColoredBackArrow"

    <style name="ToolbarColoredBackArrow" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>`

it works  why? I should do this without using theme

Comment: Are you setting the activities action bar? https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up

Comment: Yes, setSupportActionBar(toolbar) I do it

Comment: And then you do `actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` ?

Comment: @user2836202 Yes

Answer (score 0):

If the toolbar is your support action bar, then this definitely works :

```
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_back);
```

Or whatever you want to set the icon to, just that it has to be a drawable file.